# How to limit suggested applications for sociald sharing button in android

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, android-sharing

I'm using monodroid in order to developing android applications. I have a button for sharing and internet link + some text to the social networks. I'm using below code for for implementing this functionality:

```
string body= "This is something for sharing from my android application";
Intent intent= new Intent (Android .Content .Intent .ActionSend);
intent.SetType ("text/plain");
intent .PutExtra (Android .Content .Intent .ExtraText , body );
intent.PutExtra (Android .Content .Intent .ExtraSubject , "Subject");
activity .StartActivity (Intent .CreateChooser (intent ,"Share via"));
```

the chooser intent includes both social apps (like facebook and Google+ ) and other apps like Gmail and Yahoo.

How can I limit it so that just include social network apps.

Thanks